# Matplotlib slider color change

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have small question. 
How can I change slider color in matplotlib? by default it`s blue. And in my project I need two sliders, one green and one red.

here is code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
a0 = 5
f0 = 3
s = a0*np.sin(2*np.pi*f0*t)
l, = plt.plot(t,s, lw=2, color='red')
plt.axis([0, 1, -10, 10])

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axfreq = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
axamp  = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)

sfreq = Slider(axfreq, 'Freq', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=f0)
samp = Slider(axamp, 'Amp', 0.1, 10.0, valinit=a0)

def update(val):
    amp = samp.val
    freq = sfreq.val
    l.set_ydata(amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
sfreq.on_changed(update)
samp.on_changed(update)

resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')
def reset(event):
    sfreq.reset()
    samp.reset()
button.on_clicked(reset)

rax = plt.axes([0.025, 0.5, 0.15, 0.15], axisbg=axcolor)
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('red', 'blue', 'green'), active=0)
def colorfunc(label):
    l.set_color(label)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
radio.on_clicked(colorfunc)

plt.show()
```

Thank you all.

Comment: What have you tried already and what has it gotten you?  Additionally, what docs or SO posts have you read, if any?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the color property of the Slider:

```
sfreq = Slider(axfreq, 'Freq', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=f0, color='red')
samp = Slider(axamp, 'Amp', 0.1, 10.0, valinit=a0, color='green')
```

Comment: In general there are two colors for sliders: ie the background color and the color of the bar. or ie to the left and to the right of the slider location.   The `color`  property affects only the first of these. The other is set by the `axisbg`  or `facecolor` property of the slider's axis.